# RadGrid set column editable in C#

Tags: c#, telerik, telerik-grid, radgrid, radgridview

I am using RadGrid. How am I able to make whole column readonly or editable false.

Here I get the column

```
 protected void RadGrid1_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
   var colName = RadGrid1.MasterTableView.GetColumn(column.ColumnName);
 }
```

But there not property to set readonly true/false.

Is there any way I can set this column to editable false?

Answer (score 0):

Please try with the below code snippet.

1.

```
protected void RadGrid1_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (GridColumn column in RadGrid1.Columns)
    {
        if (column.UniqueName == "Name") //Your column uniqename
        {
            if (column.Owner.IsItemInserted)
            {
                ((GridBoundColumn)column).ReadOnly = false;
            }
            else
            {
                ((GridBoundColumn)column).ReadOnly = true;
            }
            break; // TODO: might not be correct. Was : Exit For
        }
    }

    RadGrid1.Rebind();
}
```

2.
[Telerik RadGrid set BoundColumn to ReadOnly in Edit Mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8774610/telerik-radgrid-set-boundcolumn-to-readonly-in-edit-mode)